# Significant delay between RuntimeViewCompiler and PageActionInvoker / PageResult

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

In a asp.net razor pages application, there is significant delay between request and response. The app queries a database and displays text in `cshtml` razor page. Database query is fast, completes under 5ms. App runs in Visual Studio debug mode without any issue. But when published to production server, there is delay of around 10 seconds on each request. The application is **published on 5 different domains on the same server but the delay is happening only on one** of them. All the configuration, IIS settings, web.config, appsettings.json are same for all domains. The only difference is domain name and database.

Investigating using [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet) I got following result snapshot. There is a visible delay on **Result: PageResult** in MiniProfiler.

[image: MiniProfiler result snapshot]

After enabling and examining trace log, I concluded following extracts. There is always a gap of around 10 seconds between category entries `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler` (Located compiled view...) and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker` (After executing action ... PageResult) There are no log entries between these two events. All other entries for a request, before and after these two events, complete within a few ms.

```
{
    "Timestamp": "11:29:25",
    "EventId": 5,
    "Category": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler",
    "Message": "Located compiled view for view at path \u0027/Pages/Shared/_References.cshtml\u0027.",
    "Path": "/Pages/Shared/_References.cshtml",
    "RequestPath": "/"
    "ActionName": "/Index"
}
{
    "Timestamp": "11:29:34",
    "EventId": 6,
    "Category": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker",
    "Message": "After executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.",
    "ActionResult": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult",
    "RequestPath": "/"
    "ActionName": "/Index"
}
```

I tried using following trace logs in `appsetting.json`:

```
"Default": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Trace",
"Microsoft": "Trace",
"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Razor": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Trace"
```

Another thing I noticed is that if I add images to the page (all under 100kb, hosted on the same server under wwwroot), the delay increases approx. by 10 seconds for each image i.e. for 3 images total delay is around 40 seconds (10+(3*10)). My Program.cs initialization is as under:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
builder.Services.AddMiniProfiler(options =>
{
    ...
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMiniProfiler();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Earlier the application `TargetFramework` was `net7.0`. I updated it to `net8.0` but the problem persists. All packages are up to date. Application runs on Windows Server 2019 (1809) under IIS 10.

I do not know how and where to further investigate to figure out the reason of this delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of different things with asp.net app and logging from within the app and MiniProfiler, I tried to shift my focus outside the app. I enabled *Website Failed Request Tracing* in IIS and analyzing the logs found that the issue was not related to asp.net code / app or configuration.

I have installed ModSecurity (Web Application Firewall) on the production server. Searching the web for causes of ModSecurity slowing down the site pointed out to the large `ip.pag` file used by it for logging. For this particular domain this file had grown to around 1 GB which was causing all the delays. To resolve the issue I had to:

- Temporarily turn off ModSecurity
- Take a backup of `ip.pag` file in ModSecurity logs
- Delete the `ip.pag` file
- Turn ModSecurity on again

And the site was up again without any issue and responding under a few ms.

I hope this will be helpful to anyone other facing similar issue.